Prepositions after "threaten"
Could you please tell me which of these sentences is/are correct?
-"Our neighbours threatened us about calling the police because of the noise."
-"Our neighbours threatened us with calling the police about the noise."
-"Our neighbours threatened to call the police about the noise."
Personally,I would use the last one, but I do not know if the rest are right.

Problems arise when you explicitly specify the direct object ("us"), which is why your last version is okay ("us" isn't present). If you include "us" this seriously restricts how you can add additional text defining the threat itself. You have to use with after a direct object here, and it needs to be followed by a noun, so They threatened us with prosecution works syntactically. But verb-based noun phrases are tricky here. The best "valid" construction I can think of is They threatened us with having the police called about the noise. Better to just dump "us"!

...maybe it's just me, but I don't like ...threatened us with calling the police because syntactically speaking I find it inherently awkward to identify the implied subject who will call the police. But there are enough written instances of "threatened him with calling" in Google Books to show that obviously not everyone sees it the same way I do.

...as in 1) They threatened him with going to the police -the implied subject of going is they, but in 2) They threatened him with going to prison the implied subject of going is him. I don't like that.
